# Orbit jQuery plug-in: How to fade in directional navigation arrows?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-plugins, fadein, orbit

I'm trying to get the navigation arrows to appear only when the user hovers over the "#featured" div, or the display. So far i have the following code which does the job, but very suddenly:

```
$("#featured, div.slider-nav").hover(function(){
    $("div.slider-nav").animate({'opacity':'1.0'}, 400);},
function() {
    $("div.slider-nav").animate({'opacity':'0'}, 400);
});
```

The time included in the .animate() function only serves as delay, unlike when using .animate() to manipulate color where it fades in the effect (although jQuery requires a separate plug-in to animate colors). So what's the best way to smoothly fade in the navigational arrows this case?

Answer (score 0):

You should apply the hover on the wrapper so you don't have to include the nav separately. That way it won't queue and fire twice.

Also use mouseenter mouseleave and put a stop before the animation:

```
$(".orbit-wrapper").mouseenter(function(){
  $("div.slider-nav").stop().animate({'opacity':'1'}, 400);
}).mouseleave(function(){
 $("div.slider-nav").stop().animate({'opacity':'0'}, 400);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this tip. It made my slider run smoother, although I still haven't figured out the fadeIn I'd like. xD

Comment: What are you trying to fade? This should fadein and out the arrows when you hover in and out. Change the 400 to 1500 and it should work now.